# In eclipse how to show exception message of debugger code executed in display window?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm running a method at a breakpoint in the code display window of eclipse. It results in an exception but does not show the exception message.

Anyone know how to see this when debugging in eclipse?

Comment: Catch the exception and print the stack trace?

Comment: It says 'Try statement cannot be used in an evaluation expression'

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: You aren't understanding me, try is not allowed in the display window during debugging.

Comment: Right. Add it to your code. Then run it. You should always be catching and displaying / handling exceptions appropriately anyways, in any code where there is a risk of an exception. Then you don't have problems like this!

Comment: You still aren't understanding me. This is not a code snippet for the source, this is me investigating the root of a different but related issue. I specifically mention display window in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Set a break point, highlight the Exception instance, and then expand it and click on *stackTrace*.

[image: eclipse debug window]

Comment: This is not where my issue is. I am trying to see the exception message that happened dynamically during code execution in the display window.

Comment: Look in the top right corner of my screen shot. You can see it there. If you want to see it somewhere else, you'll have to write code.